# how to skip the rows of a specific id in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

*what am trying to do is displaying only the fk_students who got marks in biology and chemistry and computer like 5 3 3 respectively but not 2 which considered as a failure here the result am getting also the students who got 2 marks in the subjects.*

```
*

select school_name,fk_students, count(marks),sum(marks) as total from students inner join remarks on fk_students = student_id
        inner join subjects on subject_id =  fk_subjects
        inner join school on school_id = fk_school_idd
        where marks = 3 or marks = 4 or marks = 5 
        group by fk_students,school_name
        except 
        select school_name,fk_students, count(marks),sum(marks) as total from students inner join remarks on fk_students = student_id
        inner join subjects on subject_id =  fk_subjects
        inner join school on school_id = fk_school_idd
        where marks =2 
        group by fk_students,school_name
        order by fk_students
```

- 

*the column fk_students where it contains 9 and 10 and 11 shouldn't be shown because they've got 2 mark in of their subjects which is considered failure*
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeJTP.png)

Comment: Can you share input table, current output table and expected output?

Comment: 1) Pretty sure this `5 3 3` is supposed to be `5 4 3`. 2) I don't see where you do any filterin on `fk_students`. 3) Why the `except? 4) Per @lemon you need to provide a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using "where in"
full solution is shown below

```
select school_name,st_name,sum(marks) as total from students inner
join remarks on fk_students = student_id
inner join subjects on subject_id = fk_subjects
inner join school on school_id = fk_school_idd
group by fk_students,school_name,st_name
having sum(marks)=15
except
select school_name,st_name,sum(marks) as total from students inner
join remarks on fk_students = student_id
inner join subjects on subject_id = fk_subjects
inner join school on school_id = fk_school_idd
where fk_students = any(select fk_students from remarks
where marks in (2))
group by fk_students,school_name,st_name
having sum(marks)=15
order by school_name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).